# Display phtml block in another block page

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template, magento2.2.2

As **M1** if I need to display just some phtml in another block or page, so we have to create it in a current theme then we can retreive it via xml or the other block

**xml:**

```
<the_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="block1" template="path/to/file.phtml">
    </reference>
</the_layout_handle>
```

then in the other file we get it like this: `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('block1'); ?>`

**phtml:**

```
or directly like this: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path/to/file.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

**Question :**

Directly in file I know that bu how to reproduce the same thing via xml in M2 ?

```
phtml:

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Luma::path/to/file.phtml")->toHtml();
```

**Issue:**

I have some **phtml** in `app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/template/block1.phtml`

i want to display it in home page, so in content I have this: `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block1" template="Magento_Luma::template\block1.phtml"}}` but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a custom phtml file on home page, I think there are 2 ways to do it.

First way is by inserting this into admin homepage:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block1" template="Magento_Theme::block1.phtml"}}
```

And you create your `block1.phtml` in:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/block1.phtml

Second way is by inserting the template block like this (for example inside the main content container):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block1" template="Magento_Theme::block1.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

In:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

Use the `before` attribute to position the new block where you want inside the `content` container.

For example `before="other_block_name"` positions the new block before the `other_block_name` block.

You also have to create the `block1.phtml` in `Magento_Theme/templates`

Btw, you can change the template location to any other core or custom module. `Magento_theme` is just a default example.